# Django Dynamic Admin Form

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-admin

In my Django project I have the models Product and ClothingProduct. Product has an attribute called category. ClothingProduct inherits from Product. When a Product is created where the category value == 'Clothes' an instance of ClothingProduct should also be created and then the user should be able to enter the attribute values for ClothingProduct ( trough the admin panel).
I tried the following save() method, but it doesn't work.

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.category.name == 'Clothes':
                clothingProd, created = ClothingProduct.objects.get_or_create(product=self)
                if created:
                    clothingProd.color = 'White'
                    clothingProd.save()


        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class ClothingProduct(Product):
        product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clothing_product')
        color = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text='eg. White')

#This is the admin.py content:
    @admin.register(Product)
    class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [ProductImageAdmin]
        fields = ('name', 'category')

        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
            if obj and obj.category.name == 'Clothes':
                form = ClothingProductForm
            else:
                form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
            return form

    class ClothingProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ClothingProduct
            exclude = ['product']

    admin.site.register(ClothingProduct)
```